# How to display array in JavaScript without for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

I am trying to query my information that I have been using on [Parse.com](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries).
I have an array of information that I want to query from by using they containedIn method.

Here is an example from Parse of how I can use the contained in method:

```
// Finds scores from any of Jonathan, Dario, or Shawn
query.containedIn("playerName", ["Jonathan Walsh", "Dario Wunsch", "Shawn Simon"]);
```

Here is how I am attempting this:

```
var holdingTheDaysInCurrentMonth = []; //declare array

//for loop to put info inside of it
for(var i = startDateDay; i <=endDateDay; i++) {
    var dayInMonth = i.toString();
    holdingTheDaysInCurrentMonth.push(dayInMonth);  
}

//... code to query Parse

//how I am calling my method
alert(holdingTheDaysInCurrentMonth.toString());
query.containedIn("dayString", [holdingTheDaysInCurrentMonth.toString()]);
```

On my alert I get a response back of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 when I click on the 1st and the 6th of the month(this is to be expected). I am getting no retrieved rows back from my query so must be querying wrong. How can I change my format to be used correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `join()` instead of `toString()`.

Comment: query.containedIn("dayString", [holdingTheDaysInCurrentMonth.join()]); That didn't work.

Comment: Does this? `query.containedIn("dayString", holdingTheDaysInCurrentMonth);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
query.containedIn("dayString", holdingTheDaysInCurrentMonth);
```

The second parameter can be an actual array, so there's no need to convert it to a string.